# I don't understand how to define a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> **(3)** Define a linear transformation $T: P_{3} \longrightarrow P_{3}$ by $T(f(x))=x^{2} f^{\prime \prime}(x) -f^{\prime}(x)-6 f(x)$
>
> **(a)** Find a basis for $\text{kernel}(T)$.
>
> **Solution:** $=-1+6 x-18 x^{2}+24 x^{3}$
>
> **(b)** Find a basis for $\operatorname{image}(T)$.
>
> **Solution:** $1, x, x^{2}$
>
> **(c)** Compute the $\alpha$ -matrix for $T,$ where $\alpha=\left\{1, x, x^{2}, x^{3}\right\} .$
>
> **Solution:** $[T]_{\alpha}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}-6 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -6 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -4 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$
>
> **(d)** Compute the determinant of $T$.
>
> **Solution:** $\operatorname{det}(T)=\operatorname{det}\left([T]_{\alpha}\right)=0$

I don't know how he defined the image. And letter C, I don't know what it's asking me to do. With those two I can solve the rest of the exercises.

Comment: My employer must be blocking photobucket.com, because at first this question made no sense to me until I realized that the bulk of the question is in an image that I can't see. Can someone who CAN access photobucket.com transcribe the image to LaTEX?

Comment: Thank you, someone already responded the question. I'm really surprised with how altruistic people are in this site! When I learn more math, I'll be sure to respond questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of $T$ (also known as its range, analogous to that of a traditional function) is the subspace of $P_3$ consisting of all possible $T(f(x))$. With this transformation, the range is simply $P_2$. This can be seen by considering arbitrary $f(x) \in P_3$:

$$
f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\
f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \\
f''(x) = 6ax + 2b
$$

Then $$T(f(x)) = 6ax^3 + 2bx^2 - (3ax^2 + 3bx + c) - 6(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) = -(4b + 3a)x^2 - (3b + 6c)x - (c + 6d).$$ One basis of $P_2$ is $\{1, x, x^2\}$. As for part C, the $\alpha$-matrix of $T$ is simply the transformation matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\alpha$. You can calculate this (as your textbook should explain) by applying $T$ to each vector in $\alpha$, i.e. $[T]_\alpha = [T(1) \quad T(x)   \quad T(x^2) \quad  T(x^3)]$. You will end up with
$$
\left[
\matrix
{
-6&-1&0&0 \\
0&-6&-2&0 \\
0&0&-4&-3 \\
0&0&0&0
}
\right].
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I found out how to do the problem, but didn't really understand why it was that happened. Your explanation was really clear.

Comment: No problem -- glad I could help!